# Match/Sort values on two different columns on the same sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, matching

I'm trying to solve out a recurring task that I do every week. What I do is compare sets of ID's in a column (Column A) to another column (Column E) and vice versa.
If value in first column is found in second column, the value will move to where the values is matching. If there are no matching data in either of the columns, it will just be blank.
All of the matching values will be moved down and all that has no match will be move upwards for checking.

This is the sample data below which is found in "sample" tab:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 399381935 | 375634552 |
| 407932943 | 399381935 |
| 409046041 | 407932943 |
| 448734453 | 409046041 |
| 452821913 | 431446526 |
| 459673358 | 448734453 |
| 463178020 | 448879624 |
| 485888087 | 452821913 |
| 498826033 | 458359366 |
| 498826520 | 459673358 |
| 503189964 | 463178020 |
| 509536058 | 485888087 |
| 509542349 | 497540933 |
| 510595029 | 498826033 |
| 510595505 | 498826520 |
| 510601532 | 502416642 |
| 511701201 | 502433066 |
| 512763252 | 503189964 |
| 515003633 | 506534952 |
| 515008102 | 509536058 |
| 520097636 | 509542349 |
|  | 510307762 |
|  | 510312887 |
|  | 510320772 |
|  | 510595029 |
|  | 510601532 |
|  | 511701201 |
|  | 512763252 |
|  | 515003633 |

And hopefully, after running the script, the finished data should have the result shown below where all the matched data are group below and those unique values are pushed above so it'll be easier to check:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
|  | 375634552 |
|  | 431446526 |
|  | 448879624 |
|  | 458359366 |
|  | 497540933 |
|  | 502416642 |
|  | 502433066 |
|  | 506534952 |
|  | 510307762 |
|  | 510312887 |
|  | 510320772 |
| 510595505 |  |
| 515008102 |  |
| 520097636 |  |
| 399381935 | 399381935 |
| 407932943 | 407932943 |
| 409046041 | 409046041 |
| 448734453 | 448734453 |
| 452821913 | 452821913 |
| 459673358 | 459673358 |
| 463178020 | 463178020 |
| 485888087 | 485888087 |
| 498826033 | 498826033 |
| 498826520 | 498826520 |
| 503189964 | 503189964 |
| 509536058 | 509536058 |
| 509542349 | 509542349 |
| 510595029 | 510595029 |
| 510601532 | 510601532 |
| 511701201 | 511701201 |
| 512763252 | 512763252 |
| 515003633 | 515003633 |

Below is the script I used which was suggested by @Cooper. The script works fine if there are just a few data but it doesn't perform a 100% if there are large sets of data being compared.

```
function sortof() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("sample");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1;
    if (b[0] > a[0]) return -1;
    if (a[0] == b[0]) return 0;
  })
  sh.getRange(2, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs)
  let ob = vs.reduce((a, r, i, A) => {
    let idx = a["col1"].indexOf(r[4]);
    if (~idx) {
      let t = A[idx][4]
      a["col5"][idx] = [r[4]];
      a["col5"][i] = [t];
    } else {
      if (!a["col5"][i]) {
        a["col5"][i] = [r[4]];
      }
    }
    return a;
  }, { col1: vs.map(r => r[0]), col5: [] })
  sh.getRange(2, 5, ob["col5"].length).setValues(ob["col5"]);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(ob));
}
```

@TheMaster, here's the screenshot result of the recommendation change you had on the `vs` part.
I've marked the ones in red the ones the doesn't match and orange and blue the ones that has match values but still pushed upwards, resulting in a duplicate value.

[image]

Appreciate all the assistance here.

Comment: "doesn't perform a 100%": what does this mean?

Comment: Try changing `vs` to `const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();`

Comment: @ScottHunter what I mean was it works, but not completely accurate, specially with huge sets of data. If there's only like 6-12 counts, the script does the job 100%.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for this. I updated the script and added the result screenshot on the body since I can't paste an image on the comment section. Thank again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not difficult to accomplish this with a formula so I recommend going this route:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(a_,TOCOL(A2:A,3),
       b_,TOCOL(B2:B,3),
       LABEL,LAMBDA(x,LET(s,SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)),TOCOL(x,3)&"ζ"&COUNTIFS(x,x,s,"<="&s))),
       a,LABEL(a_),
       b,LABEL(b_),
       matching,TOCOL(VLOOKUP(a,b,1,0),3),
       unique1,FILTER(a,a<>"",0=COUNTIF(matching,a)),
       unique2,FILTER(b,b<>"",0=COUNTIF(matching,b)),
       s_unique,SORT({unique1;unique2}),
       aligned,VSTACK(
                 {VLOOKUP(s_unique,unique1,1,0),VLOOKUP(s_unique,unique2,1,0)},
                 {matching,matching}),
       IFNA(QUERY(
              IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(aligned,"ζ.*",)),
              "where Col1 is not null or Col2 is not null"))))
```

[image]

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @TheMaster Holy Cow! I really I was 8/10 when in comes to spreadsheet formulas and then you showed me this. Thanks as well for this. I can use this one but it will add another columns/rows on the live worksheet so this would mess up the current file but I will keep this one.